# A game with wine on full screen is giving me trouble

Tags: unity, wine, games

[image]

As you can see game is unplayable with wine on Ubuntu 16.04. I don't know how to explain my problem. When I play it on windowed screen there is no problem. I've had the same issue with outlast as well. I was suspecting compiz was the problem, but on arch linux I could play it on full screen on gnome desktop. As I know gnome desktop uses compiz, right ? I'm not a linux newbie, I'm using it for "years" but struggled so much to play games. Now, I feel like to play some games. Do you have any suggestion ?

I've tried on wine 1.6.2 and 1.8.2.
I have AMD HD 5670 graphics card with open source drivers on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I've found the solution !
http://askubuntu.com/questions/135663/unity-shows-through-games?rq=1

"If you are having the same issue I have, and it sounds like you do, try unchecking Allow the window manager to control the windows in the Graphics section of winecfg. Works for me, no Dash or titlebar in fullscreen."

Thanks ask ubuntu and @pgschk :)

Now I can play my Horror RPG's ! Yay !

Answer (score 2):

From Ali's comment below the question:

1. Open a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
2. Set `WINEPREFIX` if needed by running `export WINEPREFIX="/path/to/wine-prefix"`.
3. Run `winecfg`.
4. Go to the *Graphics* tab.
5. Uncheck *Allow the window manager to control the windows*.
6. Click *OK*.

Answer (score 0):

This was causing me problems on Wine for fullscreen as you said.
Disabling "Allow window manager to control the windows" fixed the fullscreen problem for me, but introduces a new problem: Wine windows (explorer, etc) are always on top, until closed, no control from the panel is possible or minimizing.
Then, I made a new discovery: re-enabling the screen compositor did the trick. I can have fullscreen Wine again. Really weird. (this is on Xubuntu 16.04 Xfce 4.2.0)
Thanks very much for sharing!!